# python program runs in IDLE not in program

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a first quarter online student and I'm stuck.  My program has input to a list and then print the list in reverse order and every item in the list printed backwards.  I can get the program to run in IDLE, but when I just click on the .py file to run in the command window, when it gets to the part of the program to print the list, the command screen just closes.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
wordList = []

while word != "karyn":
   wordList.append(word)
   word = input("Let's keep going.\nEnter another word: ")

wordList.reverse()
for i in wordList:
    print(i[::-1])
```

Comment: The program is probably fine, but the cmd closes upon completion. Add a line to leave the `cmd` open, or open it manually so it won't close. Add `input('Done! Press any key to continue')` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just pause it at the end of the script (I'll assume windows here...)

```
for i in wordList:
    print(i[::-1])
import os
os.system("pause")
```